# No sound after installing 16.04.LTS

Tags: sound

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my new Asus all in one ZN270IE. 
Installation went well except there is no Sound.  I have checked, the sound is unmute.  Could not find out what is the issue.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: install `pavucontrol` to check if the correct device is enabled to it. You will need to verify it at Sound Settings, too.